# jQuery animated fade out flickers before the callback is executed (chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, coffeescript

I made a little function that allows to click on a text element which then flys (animated top/left offset with absolute position) to a specific location and disappears.

**Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6gg2/) of the problem.**

Here is my code from the click handler (in coffescript):

```
    var hoveringSelection = $ "<div class='flying cm-variable'>#{selection}</div>"

    var dropdownToggle = $ '#watchlist-dropdown'
    hoveringSelection.css({
      position: 'absolute'
      top:  window.mouse.y
      left: window.mouse.x
      display: 'block'
      opacity: 1
    })
    .appendTo('body')
    .animate({
        top: dropdownToggle.offset().top
        left: dropdownToggle.offset().left
        opacity: 0.0
      },
      {
        duration: 1500
        easing: 'easeOutCubic'
        complete: () ->
          hoveringSelection.remove()
          updateQueueSize()
      }
```

as you can see it should be at opacity 0 and then removed. The problem is that it shows for a split second (with a ~50% chance) before it gets removed.
I tested it with alerts before the .remove() is called so that the javascript execution halts, but it still did it before the alert was executed. Therefore the issue has to appear right before the completion callback of animate() is called.

I could not observe such behaviour in Firefox.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: if i remove the 'easeOutCubic' from the animate call it seems to work fine. could there be an error in the timing of the easeOutCubic function?

Comment: Hmmm, you are right with easeOutCubic, but I wonder how that can be. I don't see an error in that calculation and I wonder why it should be limited to Chrome

Comment: @Maddis I have posted an answer that I hope to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen that this is a bug (http://www.brycecorkins.com/blog/jquery-fadein-opacity-bug-in-chrome-and-ie-8/). The problem is the opacity. I made a few changes to your script to get your goal. At the end of animation I set opacity to 0.01 and then on complete I execute function that remove the element. I hope that this help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/XjesX/1/

```
$(function () {
    $.extend($.easing, {
        easeOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
            return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t + 1) + b;
        }
    });

    var mouseListener = function (event) {
        if (!window.mouse) window.mouse = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        };
        window.mouse.x = event.clientX || event.pageX;
        window.mouse.y = event.clientY || event.pageY;
    };
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseListener, false);

    var fly = function() {


        var hoveringSelection = $("<div class='flying'>A word</div>");

        var dropdownToggle = $('#flytome');
        hoveringSelection.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: window.mouse.y,
            left: window.mouse.x,
            display: 'block',
            opacity: 1.0
        })
            .appendTo('body')
            .animate({
            top: dropdownToggle.offset().top,
            left: dropdownToggle.offset().left,
            opacity: 0.01

        }, 1500, 'easeOutCubic' ,function(){
            alert($('.flying').length);
            $('.flying').remove();
            alert($('.flying').length);
      });

    };
    $('#flyBtn').click(fly);
});
```

I have added `alert($('.flying').length);` before and after remove to show that that element is removed from the DOM. If you remove that 2 lines you'll see in a better way that there is no flickering effect.

Comment: This is a proper workaround! Thanks, but I decided for the fully working easeOutQuad ;)

Comment: I think you'll need this workaround with easeOutQuad too! In that case you have the code :)

Comment: possible, but I ran several tests and it did not show the same bevaviour. Good enough for now ;)

Comment: you were right, same with Quad, I am now using your workaround! ;)

Comment: I knew because I had tried testing my script with different animations!

Comment: in the animation complete function use  `$(this).remove();` instead `$('.flying').remove();` to remove only one element (in case of multiple click)